# On find my iphone, if my 'pending: Lock Mac' is not there, does that mean it has been locked?

Tags: macbook-pro, find-my-iphone

My mac was stolen and I went on find my iphone to take the next steps :

- I tried to locate it, but it was offline (probably because there was no battery at the time it was stolen).
- So next, I decided to Lock it. The Lock was 'pending' for another day or so.
- After that I decided to erase it. So I pressed erase and then it said erase was 'pending', however the 'lock is pending' was not there.

Both the lock and erase buttons are faded out.

- Does this mean my mac has been locked?
- If it was locked, would the location have been sent to me right before?
- Can I locate/erase it now?
- If it has been locked, is it possible for people to access my information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mac is just out of juice and all those things like locking/erasing/locating will happen when your mac gets power or when someone turns your mac on.

So normally no one will be able to access your information.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just going to try and stop worrying about it!